# regular expression match with Facebook username or id

Tags: javascript

I found this regular expression in php

```
preg_match('#https?\://(?:www\.)?facebook\.com/(\d+|[A-Za-z0-9\.]+)/?#',$str,$matches);
```

The pattern is versatile so it matches:

1. http and https URL's.
2. URL's with or without the www prefix.
3. URL's with or without the trailing /.
4. Matches Facebook numerical ID's.
5. Matches Facebook's rules for usernames.

I can't understand the expression because I don't know too much about regex, the expression is correct? it matches with the items?

I need this to use in JavaScript

which is the equivalent in JavaScript?

Comment: [Google: How do I use regex in JavaScript?](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+do+i+use+regex+in+javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be the equivalent in javascript:

```
str.match(/https?\:\/\/(?:www\.)?facebook\.com\/(\d+|[A-Za-z0-9\.]+)\/?/);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/dP4Ax/)

Comment: Good job. You can play around with it here http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html or in the console.